# Java JNI error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: xxxx()V

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I have had a rough time with `JNI` today, basically what I want to do is integrate `OpenAlpr` to my `Java` project, I am using precompiled binaries which work perfectly when I run the `java_test.bat` file. At first Java kept on telling me it could not locate `openAlprJni` then I added the path to the `dlls` to my build path and system path, after which I started experiencing the `openAlprJni.Alpr.initialize(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V` which according to documentation means the library itself is not ok, but it is ok since the test program is running, I have looked at various forums and even talked to the author of `OpenAlpr` but still cannot resolve this issue, is there anybody here who has had a similar problem help me fix this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look in [com.openalpr.jni.Alpr](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/blob/master/src/bindings/java/src/com/openalpr/jni/Alpr.java). In line 12 you find:

```
private native void initialize(String country, String configFile, String runtimeDir);
```

This method is matched to the header [com_openalpr_jni_Alpr.h](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/blob/master/src/bindings/java/com_openalpr_jni_Alpr.h):

```
/*
 * Class:     com_openalpr_jni_Alpr
 * Method:    initialize
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_openalpr_jni_Alpr_initialize(JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring, jstring, jstring);
```

You will see that what you are "experiencing" is just the method signature of this `initialize` method which returns `void` and takes three parameters of type `Ljava/lang/String;`.

You probably broke the examples when you added it into your workspace (check the package names). Please be aware, the *.dll you are using was probably compiled against `com_openalpr_jni_Alpr` and not `jni_Alpr`.

I seriously recommend you to learn JNI concepts, [here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html) you find a good starting point.

Comment: thank you, I usually avoid using JNI, its always hell working with, I will look at it, thanks again.