# JNI - Connection to time and attendance terminal VF300

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to make a Java application to manage a timecard.
For this I began by writing a small program to do just a connection to the welder, I used JNI (Java Native Interface) so that I can use the functions contained in the DLL provided with the recorder.
Unfortunately after several attempts to search for the error produced by my program I have found no idea about that error.

Here's the code of my program:

```
import system.reflection.Assembly;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent;
import com.jacob.com.Variant;
import com.jacob.com.Dispatch;
public class Zkemkeeper {
   static{
        System.loadLibrary("zkemkeeper");
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Zkemkeeper csc = new Zkemkeeper();
       System.out.println("Result of adding = "+ csc.Connect_Net("192.168.0.201", 4370));
   }
   native boolean Connect_Net(String ip, long port);
}
```

The console displays this exception:

[image: The console displays this exception]

Comment: What you are actually having here is a `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, have you checked that [UnsatisfiedLinkError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261023/java-jni-error-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-xxxxv) if some package naming causes your error?

Answer (score 2):

zkemkeeper.dll seems to be DLL-COM not a regular DLL.

You should use Jacobgen to generate the COM/Java interfaces and classes for you.
I don't think that you need to use native and loadLibrary keywords nor JNA (but I know nothing about your project).

Do not forget to register your zkemkeeper.dll as explained on their website.